# validates_acceptance_of terms checkbox and Facebook connect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise

How can you force terms and condition acceptance whith facebook connect ?

In my OmniauthCallbacksController i tried

```
@user_ipad.terms = true
```

Validation of the User still fails and the user gets redirected to the sign_up form with an error message.

/app/controllers/OmniauthCallbacksController

```
      @user_ipad = UserIpad.new(:password => Devise.friendly_token[0,20])
      @user_ipad.update_with_facebook_infos(omniauth)
      @user_ipad.authentication_ways.build(:provider => omniauth['provider'], :uid => omniauth['uid'])
      @user_ipad.terms = true

      if @user_ipad.save()
        sign_in_and_redirect @user_ipad, :event => :authentication
      else
        session["devise.facebook_data"] = omniauth
        render :action=>'new', :controller=>'user_ipads', :layout => 'empty_layout'
      end
```

/app/models/User

```
  attr_accessible :terms
  ...
  validates_acceptance_of :terms, :allow_nil => false, :message => "Vous devez accepter les conditions générales d'utilisation", :on => :create
```

Thanks for your help,
Vincent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

validates_acceptance_of has an "accept" option. Rails doc says :

> :accept - Specifies value that is considered accepted. The default
>   value is a string “1”, which makes it easy to relate to an HTML
>   checkbox. This should be set to true if you are validating a database
>   column, since the attribute is typecast from “1” to true before
>   validation.

So in your case, you should replace

```
@user_ipad.terms = true
```

with :

```
@user_ipad.terms = "1"
```